# Seek a better solution: Show that ${\lim_{n \to \infty}} {(a_1 + ... + a_n)}{b_n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let {$b_n$} be a monotonically decreasing sequence tending to zero, moreover, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{a_nb_n}$  converges. Show that ${\lim_{n \to \infty}} {(a_1 + ... + a_n)}{b_n} = 0$.

The solution manual gives a solution like this (which is rather counterintuitive in my way of thinking):

i) -${\frac{\epsilon}{2}} < {\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^\infty{a_ku_k}} < {\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$, given any $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists an $N_1$ s.t. when ${n>N_1}$ this inequality holds;

ii) Trivial to show that if ${b_1 \ge b_2\ge...\ge b_n \ge 0, m\le a_1+a_2+...+a_n \le M}$, then ${b_1m \le \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_kb_k}}\le b_1M$, for any natural number n.

Let ${b_1=\frac{1}{u_n},b_2=\frac{1}{u_{n-1}}},...$, then we have -${\frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{1}{u_n}} < {\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{n}{a_k}} < {\frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{1}{u_n}}$.
Almost done.

The reordering part in the answer annoyed me quite a bit, and I had tried hard yet in vain to find an alternative proof.(Some of my pathetic tries include conjuring up something like $A_k={\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{a_k(u_k-u_n)}},B_k={\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{a_k(u_k+u_n)}}$, or trying to prove directly (which is likely untrue) $|{\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{n}{a_ku_n}}|\le|{\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{n}{a_ku_k}}|.$

Can someone please help me? I will be truly grateful. Thanks in advance.